# Wordpress is setting from header wrongly in wp_mail

Tags: php, ajax

I am sending a contact email using ajax on wordpress on submit. From the code below you can see that the FROM header is correctly set but instead wordpress is picking the header from phpmailer_init action to set as the header. can anyone help me resolve this

```
add_action('wp_ajax_contact_form', 'contact');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_contact_form', 'contact');
function contact(){
  // if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
  /* sanitize and validate */
    $name = isset($_POST['name'])? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['name'] ) : null;
    $phone = isset($_POST['phone'])? sanitize_text_field($_POST['phone']): null;
    $email = isset($_POST['email'])? sanitize_email( $_POST['email'] ) : null;
    $message = isset($_POST['message'])? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['message'] ) : null;
    $subject = isset($_POST['subject'])? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['subject'] ) : null;

    /* start sending */
    $to = 'email@example.com';
    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8', "From: $name <$email>");
    // $headers[] = "From: $name <$email>";
    $body = "Phone number: $phone <br><br> $message";
    $sent = wp_mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
    if($sent){
      echo "Email delivered successfuly";
    }
  // }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add newlines to your array like:

```
$headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n', "From: $name <$email>\r\n");
```

Comment: It seems to me that when you pass headers as an array, you don't have to add a newline character to the elements of the array. String with `\r\n` should be surrounded by a `"` character.

Comment: Interesting. To be honest, I normally concatenate when doing mine like this; `$headers = "From: \"$from\" <$fromemail>\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: \"$from\" <$fromemail>\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
`